# Moving average based on variable time and without saving values

Tags: algorithm, average

I am trying to create a moving average that:

- Doesn't save previous values.
- Is based on time passed and not number of samples. (we can't control the amount of time inbetween each sample, it can vary based on CPU speed and such).

This is the code I've come up with:

```cs
    bool init = false;
    float average;

    TimeDiffer differ = new TimeDiffer();

    public float GetAverage(float newValue, float secondsToAverage) {
      if(secondsToAverage <= 0.00001f) {
        return newValue;
      }

      if(!init) {
        average = newValue;
        init = true;
        return average;
      }

      var diff = differ.GetDiffSeconds();
      var influence = diff / secondsToAverage;

      if(influence >= 1f) {
        return newValue;
      }

      average = average * (1 - influence) + newValue * influence;

      return average;
    }
```

Where *secondsToAverage* is the amount of time it should take for the average to completely change to a new value (this is sent to the function because I don't want to handle it as state). *diff* is simply the time difference since the last time we called the function.

The idea here is that we calculate how much influence the new value will have based on the time difference for that value. Then we add it together with the previous average.

I haven't found any info on this kind of computation online, so that's why I'm asking about it. I'm just wondering if this makes sense and would work, or if there is a better way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: If arrivals were happening at fixed intervals, then incorporating the new value with Avg = W Tnew + (1 - W) Avg for some W<=1produces an exponentially weighted average tailing into the past. The way you are incorporating non-uniform arrivals - with a chopped linear approximation - won't produce a precise exponential decay. But if it's  good enough for your application, run with it.

Comment: Look at existing projects, how way do it: https://github.com/Hipparchus-Math/hipparchus/blob/17940f2fad3fb80c2d5df9f47c08adcc003b2577/hipparchus-stat/src/test/java/org/hipparchus/stat/descriptive/StorelessUnivariateStatisticAbstractTest.java#L57

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It seems the hipparchus/apache math, is using the same formula. I think my code will work out alright.